# Does the inner product of two vectors in a real vector space have to be real?

Tags: linear-algebra

My teacher made this statement in an email to me:

"For a complex LVS, the inner product between two vectors |u$\gt$ and |v$\gt$,

$\lt$u|v$\gt$ is a complex number by definition and it satisfies:

$\lt$u|v$\gt$* = $\lt$v|u$\gt$

**For a real vector space, a similar  inner product between two vectors |u$\gt$ and |v$\gt$, $\lt$u|v$\gt$ , is a real number by definition."**

This is the [definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealVectorSpace.html) of a real vector space from Wolfram Mathworld:

> A real vector space is a vector space whose field of scalars is the field of reals

According to this definition I think that $\Bbb{C}_n$ is an LVS over real numbers. Hence I feel that inner product of two vectors can be a complex number even for a real LVS.

Who is correct me or my teacher? If my teacher is correct then why?

Comment: Your teacher is correct.  By definition the inner product is the sum of products of numbers, all of which are real.

Comment: @herb steinberg why so? I have provided the reasoning of why I think that I am correct. Where am I wrong? I think that the set of complex vectors can form a real LVS. Is this where I am wrong?

Comment: You are confused about the definition of a real vector space.  By definition, all members are real vectors, with real components.

Comment: You are correct that you can view $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a vector space over the reals. But a complex-valued inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ will not work as an inner product for $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. By definition, the value of the inner product of two vectors in $\mathbf{V}$ must be a scalar, and if you are looking at $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a real vector space, then “scalar” means a real number. Also, properties are different: note that in $\mathbb{C}^1$, for example, $1$ and $i$ are scalar multiples of each other over $\mathbb{C}$, but not over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for the reply, I understood what you mean to say, my doubt has been cleared.